# To replace special character like Ç by \x01 using sed command

Tags: shell-script, sed, aix, special-characters

```
sed "s/Ç//\x01 /g" filename
```

It substitutes it to `x01` and not `\x01`

Comment: GNU sed supports backslash escapes in the replacement string, but POSIX does not require this (other than `\n` for a parenthesized subgroup in the match) and whatever sed AIX uses probably doesn't. What if anything does `sed --version` tell you?

Comment: Is the double slash before \x01 a typo?

Answer (score 1):

What is your sed version that you are using? Coz, this thing runs clean at my end.

Alternatives:

```
tr '\200' '\001' < yourfile

perl -pe 's/\200/\x01/g' yourfile

SOH=`echo x | tr x '\001'`; sed -e "s/\200/${SOH}/g" yourfile
```

Comment: Are you sure it runs in your end? With double slash before \x01? Very interesting.....

Comment: I assumed the the double slashes to be a typo, coz, otherwise it leads to a syntax error and sed wouldn't run even so ....

Comment: Maybe is not a typo and maybe this is the reason that OP command does not work... misuse of sed. By the way is `\x01` printable in your system? In my Debian prints almost nothing and ascii advises SOH (Start of Heading)

Comment: The `tr` method will only work if `Ç` is a single-byte character. And, of course, it should use `Ç` instead of `\200`, unless Sagar is working in a locale where `Ç` is this character (is there one?).

Answer (score 0):

What you posted has a syntax error: it's an instruction to replace `Ç` by an empty string, with some trailing garbage. There must be a single slash between the regular expression and the replacement pattern. To replace `Ç` by the literal string `\x01`, you would need `sed "s/Ç/\\x01 /g" filename`. The backslash needs to be doubled because it's a special character in replacement text. The remainder of this answer is about replacing `Ç` by the character whose hexadecimal code is `01`.

The `\x01` syntax to designate a character by its hexadecimal code is an extension to the portable sed syntax. It works in GNU sed (the implementation under Linux), but not on AIX.

You can insert this character literally in your script, but in many editors it's awkward to type. You can instead generate the character inside your script in a portable way by using the `printf` command and octal notation.

```
`sed "s/Ç/$(printf '\001') /g" filename`
```